# I'm using Python3.10.7, and I can't get the output of len()

Tags: python-3.x

names = ['Bobafit', 'Darth Vader', 'The Emperor']
len(names)

#its a simple list, but when I run it in the terminal, I get nothing.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to write `print`.

Comment: You should print it or store it a variable

Comment: humm, I'm reading a book, and the instructions weren't clear. But its probably my fault, because it looks so obvious. Thanks fellas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
names = ['Bobafit', 'Darth Vader', 'The Emperor']
print(len(names))
```